# Activate activity notification, after posting a comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, notifications

I studied about the current comment system. But in my case, I would like  to be notified on any activity of a question, when I commented on the question or any answer.

Surely SO has its reason, why the current state is as it is, but I was wondering, if there were others who would like this feature. Or is there an option where I can activate such behavior?

Otherwise one would always have to use @xxxx to get notified and would not get notified, if there would be a new answer or a comment on another answer.

I don't want to put the question to my favorites either, because I desire this the most with questions I am interested in answering and following, until an answer (by whomever) is stated.

On the other hand, I realize this might end up in a very noisy notification information, but I am sure, there is a solution, which would enable the easy following of a question, without jamming up favorites or the notification-bar.

*edit:*

Maybe I am describing this badly, but it would feel somewhat intuitive to me, to have like my own 'hotPage' on which I can put some questions, I want to be notified on. Yes I know - its like the Favorites - but my Favorites are more like a library to me, and because there is no grouping them into folders, I don't wan't a buch of questions there, which I am only following to answer them or comment on.

would be nice, if downVoters would contribute to a discussion on this - why do you think, this is a bad idea or bad request?

Comment: Better you use this link.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj thank you, this is a good source, but I did not find a default way in there to be notified on activities to questions one would be temporarily interested in - rss aside.

Comment: You want to get notified in the activities where you comment. There is no default way to do that. However you may mark those questions as favourites on which you want notifications. this may solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each question has a feed of its own:

> [image]

Just click it and subscribe to the feed using your favorite reader. :)

Comment: oh, ok, I must admit, I do not use feeds, like @all ^^ is there a small Tutorial here or some other refereneces on "how to use SO efficiat with RSS"? thank you!

Comment: @Jook not using it myself either, just aware it exists. You can go through [these questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss) i.e. the [meta-tag:rss] tag. :)